# How to set logback.xml file path in yaml file of springboot

Tags: spring-boot, logback

We can set the logback.xml file path using the environment variable -Dlogging.config=file:///path/to/file.
How can I set above property in the yaml config file of springboot ?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html), you can use
`logging.config: classpath:path/to/file` in `application.yaml`

Comment: I just now tried this, but with 'file' instead of 'classpath' and it didn't work. I have an external config file which is not in the class path.

Comment: @SureshAtt You don't need to use the `file:` prefix to use local system sources. Simply specifying `/path/to/logback.xml` is enough. But `file:/path/to/logback.xml` should also work.

Comment: I tried without file prefix too now. Still it doesn't pick the logback.xml. I am not sure if this is supported at all.

Comment: @SureshAtt Examples on Windows are `-Dlogging.config="file:/C:\logback.xml"` or `-Dlogging.config="C:\logback.xml"`